# In processing: How to upload a file to the internet?

Tags: javascript, upload, processing

I am an absolute beginner in web programming and in the process of writing a program that

1. outputs a .txt file
2. uploads it to a location on the internet.
3. This file should be read by another program which then displays the 
   information in the wanted format.

Programs for step 1 and step 3 are written in processing - the first in Java and the third one in Android.I need to know how to upload/edit an existing text file somewhere on the internet. (Preferably a place that can be used by `loadStrings(URL);`.)

What I have tried:

1. I have tried Node.js with tutorials from The Coding train on YouTube, but 
   since you'd need to work with the terminal this doesn't seem appropriate 
   because of the reason above.
2. The next thing I tried was using a FTP server based on this [tutorial](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/7124/text-to-ftp-server), 
   but I couldn't even get the examples to work.

What I believe I know:

1. I will need to rent/buy a domain or something that allows me to create a URL linked to a `.txt` file which can be manipulated by the first program
2. Processing probably may not the best place to do this.

I've also posted this on the official [Processing Forum](https://discourse.processing.org/t/uploading-a-text-file-to-a-server-url/9350/7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may to use this code:

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/">
   <input type="file">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Um, as I said I don't know anything about JavaScript or servers. I'd be nice if you could tell me more about how to write this file and how to execute it in Processing please. :D

Comment: You need to upload some text file to some server. Right?

Comment: Exactly. I don't own any kind of server though and was hoping to get some advice how to get one that supports just that need.

Comment: My answer explains how to post a file to a ready and working server (need to know its url adress). But if you need to create and code your server - the thing is that people which don't know programming should pay some money for this work. It is not a quick and easy task.

Comment: I completly understand that this is not an easy task and if you think I expect to much from you (which could easily be true) feel free to say so. Anyways, thanks for the expansion. This raise some other questions in me though. This is JavaScript code I'd need to put in a .js file right? If I executed it, would it directly upload the file to the given URL? And how does it get the file it needs to upload? Again, if this is to much to ask for, please ignore it.

Comment: Your didn't ask how to build a server. And I am sure nobody here will do this for free. It is the same as to write a program for free. No need to use .js file. js files are better for very big code. You may paste it inside `<script>` element. Just press the blue "Run code snippet" button here and you will see how this code works. I recommend this site to learn javascript: https://javascript.info/.

Comment: The sad thing is that javascript is used only in browsers (internet pages). On servers many languages may be used but not javascript. Node.js server language is based on javascript and very popular now. I think it is the shortest way because many things are similar with javascript.

Comment: Also learning of HTML and CSS languages is required. In my answer I used only HTML (no javascript). So you may just paste it into your HTML page (without anything additional).

Comment: This is my first post so I can't upvote your answer but I marked it as the solution. The thing about node.js is that it can only be accesed trough the command line/DOS. ...right?

Comment: It works like browser console (every console looks like windows cmd but it is not always black). You can use browser console (options => dev tools => console) to execute any javascript code. Node.js installs on server. It is like a program. You can even install it on your PC and launch your server from your PC (with white IP address). But first of all need to learn html/javascript/ssc because all pages consist from that. Servers just manage internet pages/data. The simplest html pages may consist only of html. Javascript makes changes and moving on pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload files to Internet and let everyone can access it you have to know where would you want to upload it to? Upload to your own server? Or upload to other places like google drive?

If you want to upload it to your own server (you have to buy server or cloud), you have to write some code to handle this work. It can be Java, PHP or other language. You can make a REST API for handling file upload and use HTTP request from client to upload file via that REST API.

You also use the provided API from google drive to upload file to google drive too.

My suggestion is you should search more about it. These are some keywords you can try:

- Create file upload api using java (or php, or python, ...)
- Upload file to server via API
- google drive upload API using java (or php, or javascript, ...)
- ...

Comment: Where to upload it is a part of my question. I was wondering if someone could recommend me a place to do so. I don't know anything about servers and stuff, but I'll try to get into that. Thanks for the reply. :P

Comment: The better place is your own server. You can register Google Cloud, Digital Ocean or AWS for a try. It has some free for the first time use.

Comment: Okay so assuming I found my perfect provider. How do I get a text file from my Processing sketch onto the server?